# Difference between a template with two parameters and two declarations of templates with one parameter each

Tags: c++, templates

What would be the difference between the next two declarations:

```
template<class T, class functor>
methodReturnType className::methodName(functor f)
```

and:

```
template<class T>
template<class functor>
methodReturnType className::methodName(functor f)
```

I was trying to write a method that would work with a functor arg.
The second declaration allowed me to avoid to declare the whole class as a template of both *T* and *functor*. I wanted to have a template class *className* of only one parameter *T*, but inside that class, a method had another parameter *functor*, while not declaring the whole class as a template of two parameters.
It worked, but I didn't thoroughly understand it.

Answer (score 4):

The first is a (non-template) member function of the class
template `template< typename T, typename functor > class
className`.  The second is a member function template of the
class template `template <typename T> class className`, e.g.:

First:

```
template <typename T, class Functor >
class ClassName
{
ReturnType functionName( Functor f );
};
```

Second:

```
template <typename T>
class ClassName
{
template <typename Functor>
ReturnType functionName( Functor f );
};
```

You say you didn't thoroughly understand it, but you seem to
have grasped the essential: in the second case, the class
template has only one parameter, but even after instantiation
(definition of type `T`), the member function remains
a template, which can be instantiated over many different types.
And since it is a function template, template argument
deduction applies, so you don't have to specify the type; the
compiler will figure it out for itself when you call the
function.

Answer (score 3):

Second variant is right for your case by language rules.

n3376 14.5.2/1

> A member
> template of a class template that is defined outside of its class template definition shall be specified with
> the template-parameters of the class template **followed by the template-parameters of the member template.**
>
> [ Example:
>
> ```
> template<class T> struct string {
> template<class T2> int compare(const T2&);
> template<class T2> string(const string<T2>& s) { /∗ ... ∗/ }
> };
> template<class T> template<class T2> int string<T>::compare(const T2& s) {
> }
> ```
>
> — end example ]